# Difference between directive md-whiteframe and css class md-whiteframe

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm experimenting with the Angular Material framework, and really enjoying every feature! I really like the md-whiteframe directive to raise certain containers. However, I'm noticing there are different ways of using it.

The [Angular Material Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdWhiteframe) uses it as a directive:

```
<div md-whiteframe="2">
    <span>I'm elevated!</span>
</div>
```

Whilst a lot of examples use it as a class in CSS:

```
<div class="md-whiteframe-z2">
    <span>I'm elevated!</span>
</div>
```

The documentation also specify that md-whiteframe can elevate up to 24dp, whilst the 'class version' can only go 4 distinct levels.

What is the difference between both methods? When should one use the directive or the CSS class?

I thought the difference comes from the Material Design Lite CSS library for the 'class version' and the directive version is only for Angular Material. But I didn't find a source that can confirm this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very simple. The attribute directive `md-whiteframe` adds the `.md-whiteframe-z<x>` class to the element. So, I guess you can use both. Which one depends on, if you rather do or don't use JavaScript to add a class to a element.

The pro for using JS and the directive is also that is has validation for the `dp` value. And of course it is a nice abstraction, because maybe the class name changes but your directive API doesn't.

Comment: Strange that Angular Material still leaves the option to use both. But your answer makes sense :)

Comment: They have no choice, because you always can add the CSS class :)

Comment: Right, I didn't think it through :)